# jsPlumb using a click instead of dragging to connect elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I am trying to use [jsPlumb](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/jquery/demo.html) to connect questions with answers in a quiz. I have most of this working expect I want to be able to click a question and then click an answer instead of dragging from an endpoint to another endpoint. This is because dragging on a touch device is tedious. Is this possible?

[Here is my jsbin with the dragging working](http://jsbin.com/ajideh/4/)

Here is the jquery I am using.

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
   var targetOption = {
        anchor: "LeftMiddle",
        isSource: false,
        isTarget: true,
        reattach: true,
        endpoint: "Rectangle",
        connector: "Straight",
        connectorStyle: { strokeStyle: "#ccc", lineWidth: 5 },
        paintStyle: { width: 20, height: 20, fillStyle: "#ccc" },
        setDragAllowedWhenFull: true
    }

    var sourceOption = {
        tolerance: "touch",
        anchor: "RightMiddle",
        maxConnections: 1,
        isSource: true,
        isTarget: false,
        reattach: true,
        endpoint: "Rectangle",
        connector: "Straight",
        connectorStyle: { strokeStyle: "#ccc", lineWidth: 5 },
        paintStyle: { width: 20, height: 20, fillStyle: "#ccc" },
        setDragAllowedWhenFull: true
    }

    jsPlumb.importDefaults({
        ConnectionsDetachable: true,
        ReattachConnections: true
    });


    jsPlumb.addEndpoint('match1', sourceOption);
    jsPlumb.addEndpoint('match2', sourceOption);
    jsPlumb.addEndpoint('match3', sourceOption);
    jsPlumb.addEndpoint('match4', sourceOption);
    jsPlumb.addEndpoint('answer1', targetOption);
    jsPlumb.addEndpoint('answer2', targetOption);
    jsPlumb.addEndpoint('answer3', targetOption);
    jsPlumb.addEndpoint('answer4', targetOption);
    jsPlumb.draggable('match1');
    jsPlumb.draggable('answer1');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if you don't need draggable, then you shouldn't use it, and go with normal click=connect approach.

Here is an example:

http://jsbin.com/ajideh/7/

Basically what I did:

```
//current question clicked on
var questionSelected = null;
var questionEndpoint = null;

//remember the question you clicked on
$("ul.linematchitem > li").click( function () {
  
    //remove endpoint if there is one
    if( questionSelected !== null )
    {
        jsPlumb.removeAllEndpoints(questionSelected);
    }
  
    //add new endpoint
    questionSelected = $(this)[0];
    questionEndpoint = jsPlumb.addEndpoint(questionSelected, sourceOption);
});

//now click on an answer to link it with previously selected question
$("ul.linematchplace > li").click( function () {
  
    //we must have previously selected question
    //for this to work
    if( questionSelected !== null )
    {
        //create endpoint
        var answer = jsPlumb.addEndpoint($(this)[0], targetOption);
      
        //link it
        jsPlumb.connect({ source: questionEndpoint, target: answer }); 
        //cleanup
        questionSelected = null;
        questionEndpoint = null;
    }
});
```

When you click on the question list element - it adds endpoint, when you click on the answer element - it also adds endpoint and connects it with previously selected question.

I believe this is what you wanted to do ?

[image: click to connect]

P.S. As a side note, to make this more intuitive for the user, make endpoints for questions visible first, so the user would figure out what to do - click. Once question is selected, available answer endpoints can pop-up hinting where user should click next.

Comment: Dude, I guess I was so set on jsPlumb I didn't even think of this. Brilliant!

Comment: Would it be possible that once you clicked on a question, the connection sticks to your mouse until you attached it to an answer?