# JS-Plumb: (Re-)Draw a line between two elements after clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

Edit: After trying out different hand-made solutions, I am using JSPlumb and trying to let it visually connect a clicked item from one list with a clicked item from another list (see screenshot).

[image: Basic visual connection]

I built upon this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441794/jsplumb-using-a-click-instead-of-dragging-to-connect-elements) and made it work basically, however the code provided there allows multiple connections, i.e. JSPlumb draws multiple endpoints and lines, and it doesn't react if a 'Target' is clicked first.
However, in my case there should be strictly only one connection, and JSPlumb should re-connect once I click on another list item on either side. 
(E.g. I click on 'Source 1' and 'Target 3', JSPlumb draws the connection. I click on 'Target 4', JSPlumb should keep 'Source 1' as source and re-set 'Target 4' as the target, e.g. now draw the connection from 'Source 1' to 'Target 4'. The same with clicking a different 'Source', i.e. the target should stay the same.)

In what way would I need to alter the code in order to achieve the desired re-draw?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/enoversum/pen/ZjgWZN)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {  
   var targetOption = {
        anchor: "LeftMiddle",
        isSource: false,
        isTarget: true,
        reattach: true,
        endpoint: "Dot",
        connector: ["Bezier", {
                   curviness: 50}],
        setDragAllowedWhenFull: true
    };

    var sourceOption = {
        tolerance: "touch",
        anchor: "RightMiddle",
        maxConnections: 1,
        isSource: true,
        isTarget: false,
        reattach: true,
        endpoint: "Dot",
        connector: ["Bezier", {
                   curviness: 50}],
        setDragAllowedWhenFull: true
    };

    jsPlumb.importDefaults({
        ConnectionsDetachable: true,
        ReattachConnections: true,
        Container: 'page_connections'
    });

    //current question clicked on
    var questionSelected = null;
    var questionEndpoint = null;

    //remember the question you clicked on
    jQuery("#select_list_lebensbereiche ul > li").click( function () {

        //remove endpoint if there is one
        if( questionSelected !== null )
        {
            jsPlumb.removeAllEndpoints(questionSelected);
        }

        //add new endpoint
        questionSelected = jQuery(this)[0];
        questionEndpoint = jsPlumb.addEndpoint(questionSelected, sourceOption);
    });

    //now click on an answer to link it with previously selected question
    jQuery("#select_list_wirkdimensionen ul > li").click( function () {

        //we must have previously selected question
        //for this to work
        if( questionSelected !== null )
        {
            //create endpoint
            var answer = jsPlumb.addEndpoint(jQuery(this)[0], targetOption);

            //link it
            jsPlumb.connect({ source: questionEndpoint, target: answer }); 
            //cleanup
            questionSelected = null;
            questionEndpoint = null;
        }
    }); 

});
```

Comment: What have you already tried? And why didn't it work?

Comment: Please include code examples of things you have tried. I would like to know what kind of things you have tried, because it appears you have not even tried yet. Thanks!

Comment: Straight lines would be somewhat easier, but for a curve like that you’ll likely need to use canvas or SVG, or possibly pregenerated images.  Is it only ever one line at a time? Do you need to accommodate varying numbers of elements (and therefore varying positions for elements) in each list?

Comment: I tried https://gist.github.com/alojzije/11127839 and had a deeper look into JSplumb so far. With the first one I got JS errors, apparently because it couldn't locate the list elements on page load, as they are built from two (hidden) selects’ options. No, they can be straight lines (as opposed to the image above), and it is always only one at a time, as there can be only one connection.

Comment: Also, since these elements are loaded as a list, they're not positioned absolutely, so a lot of solutions fall short here.

Comment: @MGoward Re-formatted the question, after I now used JSPlumb - thanks for chiding me properly :).

Comment: @DanielBeck Re-formatted the question, hope this makes the task and approach clearer, and provided almost-working codepen item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were already keeping track of the "source" end of the linked items in a global variable; one way of getting to your desired behavior mostly just requires keeping track of the "target" end the same way.   (There's room for improving this -- globals are maybe not an ideal strategy, and there's some code duplication between the 'source' and 'target' click handlers, but this should do for demonstration at least.)

```
  // ...other init variables skipped

  var questionEndpoints = []; // 'source' and 'target' endpoints

  // "source" click handler
  jQuery("#select_list_lebensbereiche ul > li").click(function() {
    //remove existing start endpoint, if any:
    jsPlumb.deleteEndpoint(questionEndpoints[0]);
    // add a new one on the clicked element:
    questionEndpoints[0] = jsPlumb.addEndpoint(jQuery(this), sourceOption);
    connectEndpoints();
  });
  
  // "target" endpoint
  jQuery("#select_list_wirkdimensionen ul > li").click(function() {
    if (!questionEndpoints[0]) return; // don't respond if a source hasn't been selected
    // remove existing endpoint if any
    jsPlumb.deleteEndpoint(questionEndpoints[1]);
    //create a new one:
    questionEndpoints[1] = jsPlumb.addEndpoint(jQuery(this), targetOption);
    connectEndpoints();
  });

  var connectEndpoints = function() {
    jsPlumb.connect({
      source: questionEndpoints[0],
      target: questionEndpoints[1]
    });
  };
});
```

[Working CodePen example](https://codepen.io/ook_ook_ook/pen/NWrQaOR)

Comment: That's fantastic already! There is only one thing I might not have mentioned properly - would it be possible to even have one of the right list items as a starting point, i.e. I am not forced to start clicking on the left side?

Comment: @physalis Yep! Just remove the `if (!questionEndpoints[0]) return` from the "target" function.

Comment: Oh man, that was so easy, of course, I simply overlooked it. Fair and easy, thanks a lot to you!!

Comment: Somehow the example doesnt work anymore it shows following error: ```Just HTML that goes in the <body> goes here. Learn more```

Comment: Looks like codepen got stricter about what it'll accept in its html field since that was written; thanks @Amir, I'll update it